# Is there any probabilistic proof of the Pythagorean theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, geometric-probability

There are some proofs of the Pythagorean theorem [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/). I am curious to find a probabilistic proof of this elementary theorem.

Comment: do you have reason to believe there is such a thing? I can't imagine how it would go...

Comment: I have not no idea but maybe use the geometry of numbers can be useful.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich a probabilistic interpretation (not a proof) would actually be a good question

Comment: @Snoop Well right, but the reason the existence of a probabilistic proof seems so improbably is precisely that I can't imagine a probabilistic interpretation.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich While I agree that a proof may be silly even if possible, I do see a possibility for a probabilistic interpretation

Comment: @Snoop If you actually see a probabilistic interpretation, as opposed to just the possibility of such, please tell us about it...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I may see, but I may also be hallucinating

Comment: Same question was asked on reddit a couple of months ago, https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/lr71od/is_there_any_probability_proof_about_the/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find this interesting:

$$\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^2]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]+\mathbb{E}[Y^2]-2\mathbb{E}[XY]$$

If $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)Y(\omega)d\mu=0$ (a sort of orthogonality) then $\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^2]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]+\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$ set $X-Y=Z$ you get
$$\mathbb{E}[Z^2]=\mathbb{E}[X^2]+\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$$

Comment: As expected values, variances and covariances are in the haze of inner products, that's "only" a geometric Pythagoras in disguise.

Comment: The answer sort of begs the question why abstract inner product spaces (and orthogonality) are defined the way they are (surely related to the OP's question); and it's not clear what these (presumably real valued) random variables have to do with vectors or angles.

Comment: @PeterMorfe Well, the correlation coefficient is the cosine of an angle ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe, that's true for any abstract inner product space by Cauchy-Schwarz.